# can you tell how to generate ebay user token?

Tags: postman, ebay-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrTbp.png)  getting following error

i add  url parameters client_id,redirecturl,scope and response type but getting this error

```
{
    "error_id": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Input request parameters are invalid.",
    "http_status_code": 400
}{
```

Answer (score 2):

#### User access token Steps

#1 Check App Key

#2 Registry User

#3 Get User Token

#4 API call

#### #1 Check App Key after Registry App

```
https://developer.ebay.com/my/keys
```

[image]

#### #2 Registry User - once if not user registry

I tested in sandbox,
If you use production, needs to change production URL

```
https://developer.ebay.com/sandbox/register
```

[image]

#### #3 Get User Token

Sign in from developer portal

```
https://developer.ebay.com/
```

[image]

Click Sign In

[image]

Enter e-mail of user

[image]

Enter password of user

[image]

Finally Got the user access-token
[image]

#### #4 API call

API call with #3 user access token.
In this case, user can't get the inventory due to limited scope for inventory.
But I shows how to use user-token to call API.

Using Postman
[image]

Using API explorer

```
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx?index=0
```

[image]

#### App (Client) access token Steps

Documentation in [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html)

[image]

You needs three information

#### #1 Token endpoint

sandbox - using test, use this at this time

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
```

production - using production

```
https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
```

#### #2  Get your `cleint id` and `client secret`

```
https://developer.ebay.com/my/keys
```

AppID (=Client ID) & Cert ID (= Cleint Secret)

[image]

#### #3  Enter #1/ #2 information in to Postman

#1 -> into URL with `POST` method
Select `Authrization` tab and select `Basic Auth` Type
#2 ->  Paste `client id` into `Username` and `cleint secret` into password

[image]

Change the `Body` tab and select `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Then `key` -> `grant_type` , `value` -> `client_credentials`

##### Detail Steps

Step by Step from #1 to #10.

Token URL

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
```

Input Body

```
grant_type
client_credentials
```

[image]

#### #4 Finally click Send button, then can get access token.

[image]

[image]

Comment: its generating Application token. i need user token to access get inventories

Comment: @UsamaMukarram, I added the ` user access token`  too.

Comment: Im getting user token from Api Explorer but i want to get user token from postman. am not getting usertoken from postman.and in ebay documentation  grant_type should be authorization_code https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-auth-code-grant-request.html

Comment: It means need local server(express)  with axios Post call. This is example of `authorization_code`  for Discord access token. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976480/discord-oauth2-with-node-js/74978328#74978328

Comment: I generated the access token in the last step but when I went in postman step 3, I get the same permission error.

Comment: @Ali, I updated #3 step (Detail) can you follow step by step from #1 to #10. You can get the access token.

Comment: I already have access token, my question is that you have generated the access token in last step, where would that be used now? The last screenshot you have shows access token generated but there is no further instructions on how to use it.

Comment: @Ali, This question how to get user token. If you want to real API call, you can test your API tool test in [here](https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0)