# How to properly configure Make.com with ebay developer API using OAuth2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, ebay-api, make.com

I am somewhat of a newbie when it comes to using OAuth2.0 to create secure API connections and I have gotten stuck trying to securely connect Make.com's HTTP application to my EBAY developer API via OAuth.

This question is most relevant to those who are familiar with EBAY's developer API I think.

The Make.com interface asks for the following parameters
-Authorize URI
-Token URI
-Scope
-Client ID
-Client Secret
[Make.com Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l4gG.png)

I was able to find my Client ID and Client Secret just fine but what I am struggling to find is Ebay's Authorize URI and Token URI

The Make.com documentation states:

*"Find the Authorize URI and Token URI in the API documentation of the given service (if the service uses implicit flow, you will need only Authorize URI). These are URL addresses through which Make communicates with the target service. The addresses serve for OAuth authorization.

Examples of Yahoo addresses:

Authorize URI: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth

Token URI: [https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token"](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token%22)*

However I haven't been able find those URL from the EBAY developer documentation.

It looks like it uses an RuName instead which looks something like this...

https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXXX-XXX-PRX-XXX-XXXXXx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=XXXXXX_XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope
.. (More scopes) ..

Does anyone have any past experience doing something similar with the Ebay API?

I have tried many variations of the RuName in the Authorize URI and Token URI fields and have not been able to successfully connect...

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085611/can-you-tell-how-to-generate-ebay-user-token/75087654#75087654) is detail steps  how to get the eBay access token